# When can I harvest cauliflower leaves for juicing?

Tags: harvesting, cauliflower

Does my cauliflower need all its leaves to reach  maturity? I'd like to harvest some for roasting and juicing.

Answer (score 2):

More more leaves left alone, the faster the plant will mature. Why don't you use cabbage or broccoli to juice rather than cauliflower leaves?